# Kerberos siteminder integration

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, kerberos, siteminder

We have a Siteminder running in our organization and I want to use Kerberos to authenticate users.

The setup is like this: 
Our appserver has siteminder agent that can authenticate users, agent connects to Siteminder, siteminder connects to active directory.

My question is this - what do I need to do on my appserver in order to be able to use Kerberos to authenticate users.

I might accept a good guide to how to do it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [guide](http://guireg.com/2012/11/15/protect-iis-7-and-impersonate-your-user-with-siteminder-and-kerberos/) says you need to set your service account to system and set authentication in IIS to be anonymous only.  This sounded totally crazy to me at first, but as you read on they explain how the additional ISAPI dll they have you add will intercept the SiteMinder auth and *should* pass the authentication through.  Not sure if it's actually kerberos or not...